# publishing bot from composer to azure is failing

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm using azure free trial. I suspect that might be the issue, although couldn't find anything in the docs. When publishing from composer to azure there are resources that need to be added and then there are a few optional resources. In composer I checked all the resources - although prob don't need all of them.

Then hit the create button and it says "Provisioning..." and then the message came up:

{"name":"CREATE_COSMOSDB_ERROR","message":"Error - The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DocumentDB'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions.","stack":"Error\n at new CustomizeError (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:276418:25)\n at createCustomizeError (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:276423:10)\n at AzureResourceMananger.deployCosmosDBResource (C:\Program Files\Bot Framework Composer\resources\app.asar.unpacked\extensions\azurePublish\dist\extension.js:277631:13)"}.

In the azure activity log it looks like:

[image]

I was wondering if I have to upgrade in Azure to pay as you go?
And also what the minimum resource requirements to have a bot published to Azure.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Composer does not necessarily try to use the free tier offerings when publishing. You may have to instead create Azure resources manually and then create a publishing profile from existing resources.

Comment: I think I need to register the resources from the Resource Provider tab - I followed this link - https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/how-to-solve-the-subscription-is-not-registered-to-use-namespace-in-azure-36bd2dfde3b0 - but how do I know which resources are required? I couldn't find a list in the docs.

Comment: That would depend on which resources you are trying to deploy in Composer. Depending on the capabilities of you bot, you may need one or more of the optional resources. For a simple bot, you may need none at all. Check your publishing profile to see what you've selected.